# How to handle warnings on input textbox for using special characters using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have following html markup which uses vue.js

```
<form method="POST" action="SaveCountry" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="control form-name" v-for="language in selectedLanguages" v-show="language.selected">
    <label for="displayName-{{language.value}}">Country Name<em>*<span class="vh">Required field</span></em></label>
    <div class="field">
      <input name="displayName-{{language.value}}" id="displayName-{{language.value}}" class="text v-required v-countryname" type="text" maxlength="85">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button primary button-add fn_validate_submit " id="btnSave"><span class="icon"></span><span class="label">Save</span></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

On entering the textbox with special characerts like : Trinidad & Tobago I see a warning message: Warning: No message defined for DisplayName as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```js
new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: '',
    showWarning: false,
  },
  methods: {
    scanProductId(){
      if(this.product != ''){
        if(this.validateInput(this.product)){
          // console.log(this.product);
          this.showWarning = false;
        } else {
          this.showWarning = true;
        }
      }
    },
    validateInput(str) {
        let code, i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
            code = str.charCodeAt(i);
            if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
                !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
                !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

<Input
  v-model="product"
  placeholder="Enter here"
  style="width: 300px; height:30px"
  @keyup="scanProductId" />
<div v-if="showWarning" style="color:orange">Please make sure that no special chertors</div>
  
</div>
```